# Android ImageView Animation: moving an ImageView over other views depending on their position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I need a Java (Android) code for animation to animate (move) ImageView3 from ImageView1 to Imageview2. I need the center of the ImageView3 to match the center of the ImageView1 at start and center of the ImageView3 to match the center of the ImageView2 at the end of the animation. I made a [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijVOX.gif) to show what exactly I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste this code in your animation file. Adjust the percentages to your needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="1000"
android:fromYDelta="0"
android:toYDelta="80%"
android:fromXDelta="0"
android:toXDelta="80%"
>
</translate>
```